# Python: Extracting specific columns data and storing it into variables

Tags: python, csv, class, object, variables

I have a csv file and I want to extract ratings and comments field from it and store it in two variables - rating and comment. After this process is completed I need to view the extracted data. The data stored in the CSV file is as follows:

[image]

In my dataclean python file the code written so far is:

```
class Extractdata:

    def __init__(self, rating, comment):
        self.rating = rating
        self.comment = comment
requirement_list = []
import csv
with open('D://Python//testml//my-tracks-reviews.csv', encoding='utf-8') as fileread:
    filereader = csv.DictReader(fileread, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
    next(filereader, None)  # Skip the header.
    # Unpack the row directly in the head of the for loop.
    for rating, comment_text in filereader:
        # Get the data in the variable instances.
        rating = int(rating)
        comment = comment_text
        # Now create the requirement instance and append it to the list.
        requirement_list.append(Extractdata(rating, comment))

# View the data
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sam/PycharmProjects/ReqPrio/preprocess.py", line 12, in <module>
    for rating, comment_text in filereader:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Also can anyone suggest how to access the ratings variable from this file in another file say main.py to calculate the average of ratings?

Comment: This error is telling you that `filereader` is not a list of tuples (or lists), so that you cannot iterate over two elements at at time. Try for x in filereader: print(x), to see what it looks like. Additionally, you should keep to one question per thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv.DictReader` returns an iterator that generates rows as dicts, so you should access the columns of each row with their keys instead:

```
for row in filereader:
    rating = int(row['rating'])
    comment = row['comment_text']
    requirement_list.append(Extractdata(rating, comment))
```

You should also remove the line that skips header because `csv.DictReader` already reads the first row as header for you.

Comment: r = int(row['rating'])
KeyError: 'rating'
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: It appears that your CSV file isn't parsed correctly by `csv.DictReader`. Please make sure that `;` is really the delimiter for your CSV file.